# Highlight a single word *always* in a terminal

Tags: linux-terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there a terminal emulator (like GNOME terminal) for linux/unix out there, which allows for highlighting a single word always (such as "highlight the word FAIL in red")? Or maybe is there a plugin for the GNOME terminal (if such a thing like "plugins for the gnome-terminal" exists).

The solution should highlight the word regardless of what application is being run inside the terminal, i.e. running `cat test.txt` should highlight the word as well as `make all`.

Any help is greatly appreciated by my bleary-eyed eyes.

Comment: KDE Konsole will highlight any word that is in its search bar - you can run this under Gnome.  Would that work?

Comment: [Linux terminal: Keyword highlighting similar to MobaXTerm without piping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492621/44425), [Is there a terminal emulator for linux that can highlight keywords for all the printed output](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/71706/3579),

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using bash, you can highlight all the word 'FAIL' in red using the following commands:

```
txtred=$(echo -e '\e[0;31m')
txtrst=$(echo -e '\e[0m')
bash | sed -e "s/FAIL/${txtred}FAIL${txtrst}/g"
```

What it does is creating a new bash shell and editing stdout of this new shell using `sed`.  If you want to end the stdout edition, simply type `exit` to return back to your previous shell.  You can find more color commands [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash).  The `echo -e` variation is needed to get the real ESCAPE value of `\e`.

I tried it with `echo` and `cat` in this subshell and it is working.  However, it breaks programs expecting a terminal as their output like `vi`.  I guess that it would also break programs using special output buffering.  It is also breaking commands like `echo -n FAIL` and change the behavior of commands like `ls` (ls prints many files per line when the output is a terminal, and one file per line when the output is a pipe).

Answer (score 2):

[clide](http://suso.suso.org/xulu/Clide)
works fine. I use it on RHEL 6.2, from the EPEL repository

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
cat filename|grep word -w
```

where `filename` is the name of the file and `word` is the word you are looking to highlight.